# MySQL function using REGEXP capturing and returning the second, third, and forth characters in string

Tags: mysql, regex

This is the code outline I was thinking of using:

```
CREATE function get_n_chars ( dfrom varchar(9) ) returns varchar(9)
READS SQL DATA
begin
declare d varchar(9);
dfrom REGEXP '^.(...)';
d = $1;
limit 1;
return d;
```

I was not surprised to get an error, does anyone know the correct syntax, or of this is even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in plain language what you are trying to do? If you are just trying to get characters at certain positions in a string, why use regex and why define a function? MySQL has built-in functions that will do this.

Comment: In this case, what's wrong with [`SUBSTRING(dfrom, 2, 3)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)?  MySQL doesn't support capturing string parts using its regular expression pattern matching operators, but you could [use a UDF](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php#PREG_CAPTURE_SECTION) if absolutely necessary.

Comment: The basic problem is that a have a table that has company names that vary slightly but are the same company. Example: 'Apple Inc.', 'Apple Computers', and Apple Incorporate'. I am supposed to clean this table up. I need to find duplicates based on similar names. So all three 'Apples' are 'duplicates', after identifying I need to delete the two rows with most incomplete data. So, I need to display these three rows with their id numbers then delete two. It was my thought that by using a function within a inner join I could locate these similar names. Tha nks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323688/mysql-function-using-regexp-capturing-and-returning-the-second-third-and-forth/14323963#comment19904297_14323688):

> The basic problem is that a have a table that has company names that vary slightly but are the same company. Example: 'Apple Inc.', 'Apple Computers', and Apple Incorporate'. I am supposed to clean this table up. I need to find duplicates based on similar names. So all three 'Apples' are 'duplicates', after identifying I need to delete the two rows with most incomplete data. So, I need to display these three rows with their id numbers then delete two.

To retrieve all suspected duplicates, how about something like:

```
SELECT my_table.* FROM my_table JOIN (
  SELECT   LEFT(company_name, 4) AS abbr
  FROM     my_table
  GROUP BY abbr
  HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
) t ON LEFT(my_table.company_name, 4) = t.abbr
ORDER BY my_table.company_name
```

Comment: I am trying it now, but it will take awhile to run. I did a EXPLAIN and got the following:

Comment: | id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--|  1 | PRIMARY     | name_loc   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL           | NULL    | NULL | 115099 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL           | NULL    | NULL |  10382 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | name_loc   | index | NULL          | idx_legal_name | 767     | NULL | 115099 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |